# AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present:

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ads, targetsdkversion

Here's the Error:

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: android.support.customtabs.ICustomTabsCallback","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
:app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

  > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: D:\ANDROID\project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0.jar, 
  >   Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
  >   Program type already present: android.support.customtabs.ICustomTabsCallback

Here's what on my app:

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'`

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.project.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 6
        versionName "1.5"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }

        repositories{
            maven {
                url  "http://dl.bintray.com/teads/TeadsSDK-android"
            }
        }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'

        implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.1.0'

        implementation 'com.flurry.android:analytics:11.4.0@aar'

        //implementation 'com.flurry.android:analytics:8.2.0@aar'

        implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
        implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
        implementation 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1'
        implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.3.0'
        //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.3.0'
        implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'

    // Required dependency
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:12.0.1'

    // Teads SDK
    /*implementation ('tv.teads.sdk:androidsdk:2.5.12:fullRelease@aar') {
        transitive = true;
}*/

// Teads SDK
implementation("tv.teads.sdk.android:sdk:4.3.4@aar") {
    transitive = true
}

// Teads Admob Adapter
implementation 'tv.teads.sdk.android:admobadapter:4.1.1'

implementation 'org.apmem.tools:layouts:1.10@aar'
```

}

Can you help me ? What is wrong with my app. It sync successfully but when i build it, the error appear. What should i do? Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from version `18.0.0` dependency `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads` uses AndroidX packages instead of Support Library. This dependency adds androidx libraries to your project transitively, you can check it using "gradlew app:dependencies" task:

```
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.0.0
|    +--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0
|    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0
|    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0
|    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0
|    |    +--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0
|    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0
|    |    |    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0
|    |    |    +--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0
|    |    |    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0
|    |    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0
|    |    \--- androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0
...
```

Each androidX dependency contains both `android` and `androidx` packages. Since gradle sees two different dependencies with the same packages inside, it has no other choice but to throw an error.
As a solution, you can downgrade your **'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads'** to version **17.2.1**, since it's the last version that uses old support packages. Other solution might be migrating your project to AndroidX

Comment: i cant understand.

Comment: @Jam have you tried downgrading `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads` to `17.2.1` version?

Comment: yes. thankyou. i see what ur talking about. thanks alot.